# convert sample url to http request with header android?

Tags: android, http-headers, httprequest

i want to convert the given url to HTTP Request in android

curl -v
"https://cdws.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/drive/v1/nodes?filters=kind:FILE"
--header "Authorization: Bearer
Atza|IQEBLjAsAhQ5zx7pKp9PCgCy6T1JkQjHHOEzpwIUQM"

i triew a few methods but all in vein kindly do it with explaination.

Comment: Post what you tried,

Comment: thanks i do it by myself

Answer (score 2):

```
        public static final String URL = "https://cdws.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/drive/v1/nodes?filters=kind:FILE";


        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
        String result = null;
        request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + authcode);
        //auth code is the code u get by Login on amazon link is http://login.amazon.com/android
        try {
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {

                // A Simple JSON Response Read
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                result = convertStreamToString(instream);
                // now you have the string representation of the HTML
                // request
                Log.d("RESPONSE: ", result);
                instream.close();

            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```